# Finding the value of the definite integral $\int_0^2{x\int_x^2{\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^3}}}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $$f(x) = \int_x^2{\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^3}}}$$

then find the value of $$\int_0^2{xf(x)}dx$$

I have no idea how to solve this question. Please help.

Comment: Integrate by part would be work.

Answer (score 8):

The integration domain can be equivalently written as

$$
\Omega = \{(x,y): x<y<2 ~~\mbox{and}~~~ 0 < x < 2 \}
$$
or

$$
\Omega = \{(x,y): 0<x<y ~~\mbox{and}~~~ 0 < y < 2 \}
$$

Such that

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^2{\rm d}x\int_{x}^2{\rm d}y ~\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + y^3}} &=& \int_0^2{\rm d}y\int_{0}^y{\rm d}x ~\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + y^3}} \\
&=& \int_0^2{\rm d}y ~\frac{y^2}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y^3}} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2{\rm d}y  \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{1 + y^3}} \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{4}{3} = \frac{2}{3}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks @caverac

Answer (score 3):

Using integration by parts

$$\int_0^2xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^{x=2}f(x)d(x^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x^2f(x)\bigg|_0^2-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2x^2f'(x)dx$$
$$=2f(2)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$$
$$=0+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{1+x^3}\bigg|_0^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(3-1)$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks @velut luna